# Why do my tests fail with System.Security.VerificationException?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, mstest

I'm in the process of migrating one of my projects from VS2008 to VS2010. Now that I converted all of my projects in the solution to .NET 4.0 (Client Profile) when I run the test harness, almost all tests fail with the following exception:

> System.Security.VerificationException:
>   Operation could destabilize the
>   runtime.

I've been unable to determine why this exception occurs. The tests run all fine when I run them in debug mode.

The entire solution is available for download [here](http://adamjsgenerator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/0a61869498d5).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you confirm that the application is running under the CLR 4.0? Are all projects in the solution configured to target .NET 4.0?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378895/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime) any help?

Comment: @Darin the library and its supporting application run under .NET 4 Client Profile (they don't need more than that). The test project runs under .NET 4, and it's impossible to re-target this.

Comment: @adrianbanks: no, I'm not using LINQ, Expressions or delegates.

Comment: @Dave, is there some stack trace associated to this exception so that you could pinpoint the exact location in your code where this is happening? Also did you update the reference of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` to use `v10.0.0.0` in your unit test project?

Comment: @Darin no, didn't need to update that reference, it uses that version. There's not much of a stack trace, it's always in the first method call to the library under test. Tests that do not refer to the library under test succeed just fine.

Comment: I added a link to where the solution can be downloaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the Code Coverage you activated. Disabling code coverage solves the issue. You could put the following in your AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1, SkipVerificationInFullTrust = true)]
```

and reactivate code coverage.

Comment: Good call! I'll check in a minute to see what's changed in Code Coverage for VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

First step:  Run the [peverify tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd%28VS.80%29.aspx) against the built assemblies (both test and application).  It may give you some output that helps pinpoint the issue.

Second step: Can you give us the stack trace or exception output?   The one time I actually saw an error with this was in .net 2 and was a compiler error - I had to slightly alter the code to make a call compile as a virtual rather than direct call.  Giving us the stack and the lines of code in question would be helpful.

One thing I want to point out is that apps running under the 4.0 client profile have different security behaviors than running under 3.5.  You could try adding `[assembly: SecurityRules(SecurityRuleSet.Level1)]` to your assemblyinfo.cs to run under the "old style" rules to help narrow it down.

Comment: Running under 4.0 (not Client profile) does not fix the issue. Also, all the code is available for download in the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while looking for an answer to the a very similar problem during an upgrade from a TFS2010 to TFS2012 build server.

Our projects were already targeting .Net 4.0 and unit tests were working before the upgrade.

Since .Net 4.5 is an in-place upgrade, a .Net 4.5 bug introduced by Microsoft might cause this issue in .Net 4.0 targeted projects. It is probably related to the SecurityRules answer, but internal to framework dlls (like Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework).

For us the hotfix linked below fixed the "Operation could destabilize the runtime." exceptions in what were otherwise working unit tests.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645

I hope this saves somebody else ALOT of time