# How can I prevent a VerificationException when running a test with attached debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, fluentvalidation, intellitrace

Whenever I run either of the following unit test with a debugger attached, I get a `VerificationException` inside [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) code at this point (will post whole stacktrace later if necessary):

```
at FluentValidation.Resources.LocalizedStringSource.CreateFromExpression(Expression`1 expression, IResourceAccessorBuilder resourceProviderSelectionStrategy)
in ...\FluentValidation\Resources\LocalizedStringSource.cs:line 66
```

The tests are:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        var v = new MyValidator();
        v.Validate(c);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Exception ex = null;
        var done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            o =>
            {
                try
                {
                    TestMethod1();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ex = e;
                }
                finally
                {
                    done.Set();
                }
            });

        done.WaitOne();
        Assert.IsNull(ex);
    }
}

public class MyValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.MyProperty).GreaterThan(0);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I've referenced just these assemblies in a single-solution, single-project scenario, targeting the 4.0.30319 runtime:

- FluentValidation v3.0.0.0
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework v10.0.0.0
- System
- System.Core

Some other points:

- Running the test without a debugger works fine
- Code coverage is turned off
- I've minimized the referenced assemblies down to the minimum
- I don't see any errors in the Fusion log
- I tried applying the `SecurityRulesAttribute` from the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917374/why-do-my-tests-fail-with-system-security-verificationexception)
- I tried some things from a blog post on [VerificationException and testing](http://www.thebooleanfrog.com/post/MSTest-Code-Coverage-and-VerifyException.aspx)
- Occurs under both MSTest and Resharper hosts (haven't tried NUnit, because the common thread seems to be 'under debugger'.
- Occurs when running VS as admin or non-admin

Does anyone know how I can prevent this `VerificationException`, work around it, and/or why it's being caused? It seems with so few assemblies, there shouldn't be any conflicting ones loading. I've also moved the FluentValidation satellite assemblies out of the way but still get the exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. First I'd like to acknowledge [Jeremy](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/) [Skinner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8560/jeremy-skinner) for [working with me](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/266720) to reproduce the problem. His help spurred me to try tweaking my environment further.

To prevent the problem you either have to disable [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, or you have to add [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) to the list of modules that IntelliTrace should exclude from collecting data. My web searches seem to indicate it's an IntelliTrace bug. [Jim Nakashima](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/jim%20nakashima%20-%20msft/) in his [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/07/22/verificationexception-from-windows-azure-intellitrace.aspx) says:

> The issue is that IntelliTrace itself has a bug where methods that have a boolean out parameter in an assembly that is marked as SecurityTransparent will fail when IntelliTrace collection is set to “high” which is the default in the Cloud IntelliTrace scenario.
>
> You will see this in your own code if you have a method whose signature includes a boolean out parameter and you have set your assembly security to SecurityTransparent.

I looked at my stack trace and briefly through the FluentValidation source, but didn't see this. I suspect it might be a similar IntelliTrace instrumentation bug relating to LINQ expressions.

Anyway, here's how to fix the issue:

1. In VS, select **Debug** | **Options And Settings...** | **IntelliTrace** | **Modules**
2. In the following dialog, click **Add...** and enter FluentValidation into the text box.

[image]

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but the exception is thrown from Razor, and I have no IntelliTrace... I can run the tests at home, using VS Pro, but in the office, still using VS Pro, I get the exception. How did you manage to trace the cause to IntelliTrace?

Comment: I didn't trace it directly to IntelliTrace, but inferred its code-instrumentation and Debug-mode was somehow causing this. Is anything in your technology stack instrumenting code (e.g. a memory/performance profiler, PostSharp, etc.?) It may be one of those...

Comment: TypeMock was the problem in this case. A version upgrade solved the case. It's a little bit scary that TypeMock interferes without my knowledge. I wonder what it does...?

Comment: To be sure it's doing IL gen somewhere. Creating verifiable IL using, say reflection emit, is difficult -- I've often gotten InvalidProgramException in the past when I thought I was doing the right thing.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but this does not resolve it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue and found TypeMock 6.0 to be the culprit. By disabling TypeMock Isolator (menu TypeMock -> Disable TypeMock Isolator) I got rid of the problem. This of course breaks any TypeMock dependent test.

Note that adding FluentValidation to IntelliTrace exceptions does not resolve the issue when TypeMock is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my Asp.net MVC 3 application had a reference to FluentValidation.dll and FluentValidation.mvc.dll files.

I removed the references and installed the FluentValidation for MVC 3 using nuget package manager and It worked.

It downloaded FluentValidation.Mvc version 5.0.0.1