# RazorEngine throwing VerificationException in testProject

Tags: c#, .net, razorengine, verificationexception

I'm trying to use `RazorEngine` to generate a `FlowDocument` in a WPF Application.

Including, and using, `RazorEngine` in the application seems to work fine, but as soon as I try to use it in a testproject, I get the following exception:

```
System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.Web.Razor.CSharpRazorCodeLanguage..ctor()
RazorEngine.Compilation.CSharp.CSharpRazorCodeLanguage..ctor(Boolean strictMode)
RazorEngine.Compilation.CSharp.CSharpDirectCompilerService..ctor(Boolean strictMode, Func`1 markupParserFactory)
RazorEngine.Compilation.DefaultCompilerServiceFactory.CreateCompilerService(Language language)
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate, Type modelType)
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String razorTemplate)
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String razorTemplate)
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String razorTemplate)
RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(String razorTemplate)
TestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\users\vvi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RazorEngineSpike\TestProject1\UnitTest1.cs: line 17
```

I have tried to look at potential solutions to `VerificationException` problems described elsewhere without any luck.

Does anyone have any clue of why this exception is thrown, and what I can do to prevent it?

**Update:** Running the test with TestDriven.Net works ok, but the standard VS and R# testrunners fail. I also tried to create a similar project at home, and there it seems to work ok, so something in the developer environment seems to be the cause. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845439/how-can-i-prevent-a-verificationexception-when-running-a-test-with-attached-debu) seems very similar, but unfortunately I have no IntelliTrace to disable...

Answer (score 0):

Turned out is was TypeMock that caused this error. By disabling TypeMock, the test runs without failure.