# Windows 8 Consumer preview "System.Security.VerificationException"

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml

I am attempting to run an existing WPF application on Windows 8 Consumer preview, and I keep getting the error:

> System.Security.VerificationException

This application has worked on countless Windows 7, and Windows 8 Dev preview editions with no errors. No changes were made to the code, yet it now crashes on Windows 8 Consumer editions consistantly.

I have searched on the error message itself, and there is no information there. It looks like the 3rd party controls might not be getting approved to run? The stack is pointing to `Visifire.Charts.Chart.ctor()`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917374/why-do-my-tests-fail-with-system-security-verificationexception) could help you.

It describes how to avoid the exception by modifying the *AssemblyInfo.cs* of your project. Though it's not explaining why this just happens in Win 8 CP. You should maybe contact the developers of the chart control.