# Issue accessing fields in generic base class using Fody

Tags: fody

Consider the following test code structure:

```
class TestClass<T>
{
    public object TestObject;
}

class TestClass2<T> :TestClass<T>
{
    public int TestMethod()
    {}
}
```

When I add `Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldfld, TestObjectField)` to `TestMethod`, I get the following result:

`ldfld class Object TestNamespace.TestClass``1`::TestObject`

This causes an issue in the secure plugin system of Dynamics CRM (more information could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378895/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime)). However, when I add `TestObject = new object()` to `TestMethod`, I get the following result, which runs fine:

`ldfld class Object class TestNamespace.TestClass``1`<!T>::TestObject`

This only happens when the object I am trying to access is in a generic base class. Is there a way that I can simulate the desired result from within Fody please?

UPDATE:

I managed to partially solve the issue by using the following lines:

```
var testObjectFieldRef = testObjectFieldDefinition?.Resolve().GetGeneric();
var testClassTypeRef = testObjectFieldRef?.DeclaringType.Resolve().GetGeneric();

if (testClassTypeRef != null)
{
    testObjectFieldRef.DeclaringType = testClassTypeRef;
}
```

It seems that by default the ModuleDefinition does not provide a generic type/field definition; so it has to be done explicitly. In addition, the types of the generic parameters are not specified, so it's still an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by using the following code ([reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mono-cecil/vtt25K-8tFs)):

```
var genericBaseType = (GenericInstanceType) testClassTypeRef.BaseType;
var genericArgs = genericBaseType .GenericArguments;
var fullBaseTypedName = genericBaseType.ElementType.MakeGenericInstanceType(genericArgs.ToArray()).FullName
```

Which returns `ldfld class Object class TestNamespace.TestClass``1`<!T>::TestObject` as required. It will also fill in the type of the type parameter (in place of `<!T>`) if given in the derived class.